# Is there a way to use the Core Animation timers?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have a CALayer which its position needs to be recomputed as often as possible. I'm currently using a NSTimer for that matter, but I would prefer to hook myself into Core Animation directly.

When you add an animation to a layer, the values are refreshed as often as possible without any timers. Is there any way to use this mechanism? I was thinking about rolling my own CAAnimation subclass, but that doesn't seem to be feasible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html).

---

If you want to support devices ≤ 3.0, you need to use the *undocumented* GSHeartbeat. I do not recommend this even if you target for Jailbroken devices.